# How do I verify Google OAuth authorization server's response in Python?

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

[Step 5](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code) of Google's `Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications` [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) says:

> On your callback page, use the `google-auth` library to verify the
>   authorization server response. Then, use the flow.fetch_token method
>   to exchange the authorization code in that response for an access
>   token

1. How do I use the `google-auth` library to verify the authorization server response? I found the method `verify_oauth2_token(id_token, request, audience)` in `google-auth` library (doc [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#google.oauth2.id_token.verify_oauth2_token)), but this only verifies ID token.
2. When the above mentioned Google doc says `verify the authorization server response`, do they mean verify only the ID token? If not, how do I verify the access token? What other parts of the `authorization server response` do I need to verify?

Comment: the client library should handle that for you.